# Showing alert box in abstract class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, abstract-class

Hey all I am very new in Android app development. Just a quick solution I have abstract base class. I want to display alert box in this abstract class but I cannot pass context in it due to which dialog is not shown no solution found on internet so far. Any sugessions from experts are highly apperciable
My Abstract class code :

```
abstract class BaseViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {


    fun getErrorResponse(error: String? = ""): String {

        return try {
            val errorObj = error?.let { JSONObject(it) }
            if (errorObj?.has("Code") == true) {

                if (errorObj.getInt("Code") == 450) {
                     AlertOP.showResponseAlertOK(
                                requireContext(), "Error",//problem part
                                Please call 911 for further assistance."
                            )
                    }
                "Something went wrong while processing your request."

            } else {
                val errorDto =
                    GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(errorObj.toString(), ErrorDTO::class.java)

//            if (!errorDto.errors.isNullOrEmpty())
//                errorDto.errors[0].error
//            else
                if (errorDto.response != null)
                    errorDto.response.toString()
                else
                    errorDto.message.toString()
            }

        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
            "Unexpected error occurred while parsing response"
        }

    }
```

Comment: have you tried higher order functions

Comment: @HaseebHassanAsif OP mentioned they are very new to android development, i doubt they know what you're asking about :)

Comment: your viewmodel should probably not be responsible for creating dialogs, make use of LiveData or callbacks or any other form of observable pattern where you can listen to changes so that you know when to show the dialog or when to hide it in your activity/fragment

Comment: @a_local_nobody point taken.

Comment: Please any working example?

Comment: if you make ``app`` a ``val``, it'll be available to your methods, and you can access ``app.applicationContext``. That may or may not be useful for what you're doing (you often need an ``Activity`` context that has its own ``Window`` if you're displaying things) - like a_local_nobody is saying, you shouldn't be forcing UI changes inside something that's not part of the UI layer, and that's why it's hard to do. Your UI components (Activities, Fragments) should connect to the ViewModel, and that should push an event they can react to and display a thing